# How to load a page on IE without having Angular to redirect to the non-html5 version?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

My angular app is living at /search, the rest of the application is a standard Rails app.

When I open the page /search on IE9, Angular does a redirection to /#!/search , reloading the page entirely. The server is then given the root url '/' (as the hash bang is not passed server side) and I end up on the wrong page.

How can I make angular **only change the url** from /search to /#!/search **without reloading the whole page** (without doing a server side call)?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue recently myself and it seems to be tied to this issue.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1179

I would remove the # from inside your href.  What is happening is IE is not letting angular handle the routing, so it sees href="#" and reloads your page to /#

Comment: This actually happens when I load the page, not even when somebody clicks on a link: when you open /search on IE9, it reload the page entirely on /#!/search. What I would like is a redirect without reloading the page.